How to get cEDA values from Pixel watch 2
Currently, I am trying to develop an app that measures cEDA with the Pixel Watch 2 and analyzes it with the Pixel 5. Is it possible to access the cEDA values measured with the Pixel Watch 2 from an android phone?
I would like to know whether it is possible to access the cEDA value and with which API.

I have no idea what cEDA is, BUT to get any watch data you would need a watch app installed communicating with your phone app... You can use the "Wearable Data Layer API" for the communication... I don't know what API you would need for the CEDA, sorry
